# Speed up SQL Server AFTER INSERTED trigger

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-trigger

I have a SQL Express 2019 server with a table on which I created a trigger that updates a row of that table when another row is inserted. I have to INSERT about 100,000 rows a day. Unfortunately the insert takes about 1-2 hours with the trigger, which is okay but frustrating while testing. 
This is my table structure:

```
    [ID] BIGINT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, 
    [REPORT_ID] BIGINT NOT NULL, 
    [CLUSTER_ID] BIGINT NOT NULL, 
    [ID_NEXT] BIGINT NULL, 
    [CREATED_AT] DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 
    [ID_SUCCESSOR] BIGINT NULL, 
    [CREATED_AT] DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT GETUTCDATE(), 
    CONSTRAINT [FK_CRASHREPORTS_REPORTS2CLUSTERS_CRASHREPORTS] FOREIGN KEY ([REPORT_ID]) REFERENCES [CRASHREPORTS]([ID]),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_CRASHREPORTS_REPORTS2CLUSTERS_ID_PREV] FOREIGN KEY ([ID_NEXT]) REFERENCES [CRASHREPORTS_REPORTS2CLUSTERS]([ID]),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_CRASHREPORTS_REPORTS2CLUSTERS_ID_PREV] FOREIGN KEY ([ID_SUCCESSOR]) REFERENCES [CRASHREPORTS_REPORTS2CLUSTERS]([ID]),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_CRASHREPORTS_REPORTS2CLUSTERS_CRASHREPORTS_CLUSTERS_ID] FOREIGN KEY ([CLUSTER_ID]) REFERENCES [CRASHREPORTS_CLUSTERS]([ID])
```

And this is my trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[update_prev_after_insert]
    ON [dbo].[CRASHREPORTS_REPORTS2CLUSTERS]
    AFTER INSERT
    AS
    BEGIN
        MERGE INTO [dbo].[CRASHREPORTS_REPORTS2CLUSTERS] T
            USING inserted I
            ON T.ID != I.ID AND T.ID_SUCCESSOR is NULL and T.REPORT_ID = I.REPORT_ID
        WHEN MATCHED THEN
        UPDATE SET ID_SUCCESSOR = I.ID;
    END
```

Everything works as expected but really slow. Does anyone knows how to speed this up?

Comment: Make sure you have an index on REPORT_ID, ID_SUCCESSOR and ID (in that order). If that doesn't help, upload the actual execution plan to [Paste The Plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/) and add the link to your question.

Comment: @DanGuzman Thank you! It still takes like 2 Minutes for the insert but that's totally acceptable

Comment: Since you're only updating, you could try rewriting the `MERGE` to an `UPDATE`

Comment: Is there actually a requirement to insert via trigger? any reason you can't just insert into a staging table and update from that? Then you can put an index on the source table as well.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid I'll try replacing it with an UPDATE. Thanks! Also I thought about a staging table but I really couldn't find out how to do it using Microsoft SQL as I'm a newbie with it.